# How to apply Monte Carlo cross validation to multiple linear regression in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, linear-regression, cross-validation, montecarlo

everyone.

So, I am relatively new to Python and I am trying to predict a numeric variable based on 10 different numeric inputs. In particular, I am trying to apply multiple linear regression, but would like to add Monte Carlo cross-validation in the train-test-validation phase. So, I wrote a code that looks like this:

```
#I have imported libraries
#imported the dataset
#then created X and Y df. 
#then split the data into training and testing, with validation parameters as follows:

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, random_state=np.random.randint(1000), test_size=0.3)

# I have used np.random.randint(1000) as a Monte Carlo cross validation.

The code used for regression is:

#Linear Regression Model
regressor = linear_model.LinearRegression()
regressor.fit(X_train, Y_train)
y_predLR = regressor.predict(X_test)
lin_mse = mean_squared_error(y_predLR, Y_test)
lin_rmse = np.sqrt(lin_mse)
```

My question is: is this the right way to apply Monte Carlo cross validation?

After this, I applied MLR, and with each run of the code, the R squared, MSE and other values change, so I am guessing the Monte Carlo worked. If so, is there any way to get the same results with each run, but at the same time to use MCCV?

Moreover, the goal is to also develop an ANN model (also with Monte Carlo), and eventually to compare MLR and ANN, and then make predictions for the future period using the best developed model. I read someplace that MCCV can not be used when making predictions, is this right?

Many thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

In order to apply MCCV you should run the process of randomly generating (without replacement) the training set and the test set multiple times.

So, roughly speaking, you need to insert your code (generation of training/test sets, learning and prediction) inside a `for` loop.

**Note that** the partitions are generated independently for each run, therefore the same data point can appear multiple times in the training (test) set, which is, in fact, the significant difference with k-fold cross validation.